# Get back original word doc after converting to pdf

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

Unfortunately I submitted an assignment at university after converting a word document to a pdf with <strike>pandoc</strike> word, where I now realize some of my text was hidden since the text box was too small to fit it all.

I lost marks because of this and am now wondering if they can be recuperated by converting it back to a word document that still has that data?

I assume it isn't possible and, admittedly, I'm a bit ignorant of how the conversion process works. If anyone has any ideas that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Microsoft Word can convert to PDF without Pandoc. Is there some other reason you chose to use Pandoc?

Comment: @AdamLimbert Come to think of it, I think I did use Microsoft Word after trying pandoc and realizing Word did what I wanted.

I solved this problem for myself by using dropbox and getting the logs back from before I submitted the assignment. However, I am sure someone else will benefit from an answer to this.